# Scanner problem - Espon Stylus NX420 All-In-One

Tags: wireless, drivers, scanner, epson

I have an Epsom NX420 all-in-one printer. The printer was just plug & play and works fine as a wireless network printer....but I cannot get the scanner to work. It seems that this printer is not supported on the Epson page. I have also tried plugging it into one of the PC's here (same OS). I have tried the answers on other pages with the same printer - they are using older OS and resource pages were in Chinese.

Any scanner program is OK as long as it works.

Can anyone help please?

PS: I am a newbie to Linux but don't mind sudo apt-get installations, in fact I find them easier. Clear instructions in English please.

Answer (score 0):

It is supported.

1. Go to [Epson Drivers Site](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule)
2. Search for NX420
3. Download

   ```
   iscan_2.30.1-1~usb0.1.ltdl7_amd64.deb
   iscan-data_1.36.0-1_all.deb
   ```

for scanner driver, and network plugin for scanning over network

```
    iscan-network-nt_1.1.1-1_amd64.deb
```

These packages are for 64-bit system

4. Place these files to your home folder and run in terminal

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i iscan*.deb
   ```

To setup scanning over the network you need to edit file `/etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf` and add there a line

```
net <scanner_ip_address>
```